# on submitting request control is always picking up GET method and not POST

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tiles

I am trying this using spring3 hibernate3 and tiles2.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/capturedetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getcapturedetails(Model model, HttpSession session,
                 HttpServletRequest request) {

Customer customer=new Customer();
          model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
          return "capturedetails";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/capturedetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addcustomer(
                 @ModelAttribute("Customer") Customer customer, Model model,
                 HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

                       custBarcodeService.saveCustomer(customer);

                       model.addAttribute("customer ", new Customer());
                       return "capturedetails";
   }
```

Upon submitting request control it always picking up GET method and not POST...
How can I fix this?

Comment: Show how you are doing the post request, please.

Comment: How do send your request? Using AJAX or any other way? Share some code

Comment: i am not sending it using AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have multiple form-element open...Check your tiles layout files and remove the multiple form elements and then try to post.
Because the same solution solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issue in the past. In my case I was trying to make a POST request from postman with a `json` body to an endpoint which was receiving the data in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format on the controller side.

Note that if you are using `@ModelAttribute` in your post controller method, it receives the data in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format. If this case, then possible solutions would be

1. make the post request method receive `json` data by using `@RequestBody`:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/capturedetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addcustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer, Model model,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

                  custBarcodeService.saveCustomer(customer);

                  model.addAttribute("customer ", new Customer());
                  return "capturedetails";
   }
   ```
2. Send data in `x-www-form-urlencode` format from rest client

Comment: now i did it using @RequestBody and deleted my GET method and now its giving 405 'Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Then I think there must be some problem in making the POST request.  Could you please show how you are doing the post request?

Comment: <form:form id="capturedetails" commandName="Customer" name="capturedetails" action="/capturedetails" method="POST">
<div><label for="fname">First Name:</label><form:input type="text" name="fID" id="firstname" path="firstname"></form:input></div>
<div><label for="emailid">Email ID:</label><form:input type="text" name="eID" id="email" path="email"></form:input></div>                                                          
</div><button type="submit">Add</button></div>
</form:form>

Comment: above is my jsp snippet from where i am making my POST request.